# Configuring Serial COM ports connection between Win host and Ubuntu gues

Tags: linux, serial-port, port, virtualbox

first of all I would like to say that I am new to this topic.

I have Samsung Artik710 controller (Arduino like controller), with Ubuntu OS. This controller going to substitute old self made OS controller based on serial connection (RS232) in my company.

Now comes the problem.

The app that communicates with the controller, and opens the serial ports, its windows app only, and I need to code my new controller in Ubuntu OS on my virtualBox.

I tried to configure 2 virtual ports that the main idea is that my app on my host machine (Win OS) will connect to COM2 and automatically will send the data to COM3 that will connect to my controller in the Ubuntu guest on my virtualBox machine.

Here you can see picture of the virtual COM ports in my device manager in my Windows host.

[image: device manager capture]

I heard that there is a way to solve this problem is somehow in the serial port configuration in VirtualBox or maybe to create some pipe to past the data, but so far coudln't find something effective.

So anyone know how to  solve this??maybe there is another solution?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/436049/how-to-use-host-serial-port-from-guest-in-virtualbox